# TIdCmdTCPServer and data synchronization with main thread [anomaly?]

Tags: delphi, indy10

Situation looks like this. External application client.exe sends a command **MONITOR_ENCODING** every ~250ms to the server. In server application I use **IdCmdTCPServer1BeforeCommandHandler** to read sent command from client. 
I copy received command (**AData** string) to global variable **command** and then show it in memo1. Meanwhile I have constantly running TSupervisorThread which copies global variable command to local Copiedcommand variable and then assigns new text to command variable. Is this an expected behaviour that from time to time instead of MONITOR_ENCODING text I get RESET?

[image]

```
procedure TForm1.IdCmdTCPServer1BeforeCommandHandler(ASender: TIdCmdTCPServer; var AData: String; AContext: TIdContext);
begin

  command:=AData;  //command is a global variable
  form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(form1.Memo1.Lines.Count+1)+'|'+IntToStr(GetTickCount)+'|'+command);

end;

procedure TSupervisorThread.CopyGlobalVariables;
begin

  CopiedCommand:=command; //Copiedcommand declared in TSupervisorThread
  command:='RESET'; 

end;

procedure TSupervisorThread.Execute;
begin

  while Terminated=false do
  begin
    Synchronize(CopyGlobalVariables);
    sleep(250);
  end;

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the `OnBeforeCommandHandler` event is not the correct place to read commands with `TIdCmdTCPServer`. You are *supposed* to add an entry for each command to its `CommandHandlers` collection and then assign an `OnCommand` handler to each entry.  The `OnBeforeCommandHandler` event is triggered before `TIdCmdTCPServer` parses a received command. That is OK for logging purposes, just make sure you don't use it to drive your processing logic. Leave that to the individual `OnCommand` events.

But, either way, command reading is done in a worker thread. You are not synchronizing with the main UI thread when adding received commands to your UI. You MUST synchronize. There are many ways to do that - `TThread.Synchronize()`, `TThread.Queue()`, `TIdSync`, `TIdNotify`, `(Send|Post)Message()`, etc, just to name a few.

More importantly, you have 2 threads (or more, depending on how many clients are connected at the same time) fighting over the same global variable without syncing access to it at all. You need a lock around the variable, such as a `TCriticalSection` or `TMutex`, or use Indy's `TIdThreadSafeString` class.

But, that won't solve the race condition that your code has. Between the time that your `OnBeforeCommandHandler` assigns a new value to `command` and the time that it reads `command` back to add it to the UI, your `TSupervisorThread` is free to modify `command`. That is exactly what you are seeing happen.  It is not an anomaly in Indy, it is a timing issue in your code.

The easiest solution to that race condition is to simply add `AData` to your UI instead of `command`. That way, it won't matter if `TSupervisorThread` modifies `command`, your UI won't see it.

But, why are you using a global `command` variable at all? What is its real purpose? Are you trying to make an outside thread modify the commands that `TIdCmdTCPServer` parses? You are not controlling which clients get to parse real commands and which get fake commands. Why are you doing this?

Besides that, having `TSupervisorThread` perform 99% of its work in the main UI thread is a poor use of a worker thread, you may as well just use a `TTimer` in the UI instead. Otherwise, you need to coordinate your threads better, such as by using `TEvent` objects to signal when `command` is assigned to, and when it is reset.

I think you need to rethink your design.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that Only ONE client will be connected. 
So Are you saying that code in TForm1.IdCmdTCPServer1BeforeCommandHandler is not executed in main application thread? I'm confused now.

Comment: @Atak_Snajpera it does not matter how many clients you have connected, you still have a race condition, and you are experiencing side effects of that. And no, the `OnBeforeCommandHandler` event (or any other event of `TIdCmdTCPServer`) does not run in the main UI thread, that is why you MUST sync with the main UI thread when accessing UI controls. Indy servers are multi-threaded components, clients are handled by worker threads, and client-related events run in the context of those threads.